# Deleting CoreData journaling mode creates new store WITH journaling mode

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios7

I am trying to turn off journaling mode in my CoreData store.  This is my code, which just creates a new CoreData store exactly like the old one (with journaling mode) without migrating the data.  What's wrong here?

```
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
NSString *applicationDocumentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *urlString = [applicationDocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"saori.sqlite"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlString];
NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *psc = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"journal_mode":@"OFF"};
NSDictionary *opts = @{NSSQLitePragmasOption:dict};
NSError *theError;
if (![psc addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:url options:opts error: &theError ]) {
   NSLog(@"\n\nDisable journaling failed with error: %@", theError);
}
```

Comment: 1. How are you determining that journaling mode is on? 2. Why are you ignoring the error returned by addPersistentStoreWithType?

Comment: @quellish: Sorry for the delay; electrical storm here and power was lost to ISP's tower... I know journaling mode is on because 3 files are created each time after I delete the store; no excuse for ignoring the error... will change the code tomorrow.  Thank you...

Comment: double check that when you delete the store that you are deleting all the files. The best way to do so (for several reasons) is to give the data it's own directory, and delete that. Remember any delete operation should go through an NSFileCoordinator, and preferably when CoreData does not have a store pointing to that location. I can confirm that on both MacOS X and iOS that `journal_mode` OFF is producing only one file. When I use SQLite to check the store when opened read only it does show as journal_mode OFF.

Comment: @quellish: Deleted all 3 files using Finder; changed code (see above) and it still creates a NEW file with journaling mode - it does NOT migrate old file either!

Comment: Not migrating the old file would be expected - it does not know that you moved from WAL to OFF. It just would not use the WAL file. Using your code above, I am seeing it create only 'saori.sqlite'. Perhaps somewhere else in your application a store is being added with the same name, URL, and WAL?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on sqlite.org:

> The DELETE journaling mode is the normal behavior. In the DELETE mode, the rollback journal is deleted at the conclusion of each transaction. Indeed, the delete operation is the action that causes the transaction to commit.

Thus, the journaling files are deleted, but it does not "switch off" journaling, so they will be immediately recreated. You can, however, set journaling to "OFF":

> The OFF journaling mode disables the rollback journal completely. No rollback journal is ever created and hence there is never a rollback journal to delete. The OFF journaling mode disables the atomic commit and rollback capabilities of SQLite.

Comment: deleted all CD stores, ran code above and it STILL creates a CD store with journaling mode on... substituted OFF for DELETE - made no difference.